# Partial Implementation of create-react-app to a website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm currently developing a website/webapp (I don't really know the clear distinction between it) for my school project. Initially I was planning to develop entirely through just HTML/CSS and JS, however, my adviser told me to use react framework for parts of the pages instead of just doing it with Java for the sake of simplicity. This has been really messing me up since I have no background in web development and I'm confused in general.

I currently have all of the HTML pages styled with CSS, and I was able to transition part of the web-app to react using create-react-app. However, I have no clue how to connect these two.

I created the my-app folder inside the main directory which contains most of the HTML folders, but how would I go by to
  1. Access the react app from the HTML page?
  2. Access the HTML page in the main directory from the react app?

Following is my directory as a reference

```
mainDir
  |_____bunch of html files
  |_____css //contains all css files
  |_____img // contains all images
  |_____my-app
           |____all the files created by create-react-app
```

Approaches I have tried: 
- using the  in the HTML pages in the main directory to jump to index.html in the my-app file to load the app
- changing the file path on the  tag inside the App.js render() function of each class to something like `../../welcome.html` which is the relative path to an HTML in the main directory.

Thank you for your help in advance. I'm welcome to any and all suggestions! If there isn't enough information to assess the situation, please let me know!

Comment: I strongly disagree that combining your HTML/CSS pages with React will simplify anything. You would be much better off using React for your whole application, but also I would say that you should first start with making a simple HTML website with different pages, because you'll need HTML and CSS nontheless. Short answer you can link them with simple links.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, create-react-app may very likely be overkill for dipping your toes in the water.  I'd recommend checking out some less all-in approaches, the react site mentions a few, in particular [how to add React to an HTML page](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#add-react-to-a-website)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! After all, I went on taking a route to manually create each page since it only had 10 variations of it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Checkout

This **[Example source code](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6668a1f6986742109c00a581ce704605)**, from React.js: ["Add React in One Minute"](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) guide.

#### What is it?

It's a super bare-minimum implementation of React using:

- 1 x `.html` file
- 1 x `.js` file

Given your current setup, I'd say it's a lot simpler than trying to incorporate `create-react-app`.

Let me know if this helps; I'm happy to delete this if it's not useful.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out!